# Sincronizar un ViewPager con una BottomNavigationView en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un `ViewPager` y un `BottomNavigationView` que al seleccionar un elemento se situa a la pagina correspondiente dentro del `ViewPager`, pero si cambio de pagina el item del `BottomNavigationView` no cambia.

El cambio de pagina del `ViewPager` lo detecto usando `OnPâgeChangeListener` y obtengo la posición de la página.

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
DemoFragmentAdapter adapterViewPager = new DemoFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        //aqui es donde se debe cambiar el item del navigation correspondiente a la posición que este el viewpager
    }
});
```

¿Cómo se sincroniza la `BottomNavigationView` con un `ViewPage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro de tu metodo onPageSelected podrias ver la forma de encontrar el item especifico de tu navigationView utilizando el position que te retorna.
te dejo un ejemplo.

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
}
```